# dataframe lookup using another dataframe as column reference

Tags: python, pandas

I have DF A with 3 columns (L,M,N) and n rows as:

```
L  M  N
1  2  3
4  5  6
7  8  9
```

And DF B with 2 columns (X and Y) and n rows as:

```
 X   Y
'L' NaN
'M' 'N'
'N' 'L'
```

And I want a DF with n rows like:

```
1  NaN
5   6
9   7
```

Basically, each row in DF B determines which columns in DF A to keep

TIA

Comment: What kind of dataframe?

Comment: @HenryEcker presumably a Pandas one. Is there another kind?

Comment: [tag:pyspark] is also rather common, although there are several others like [tag:py-datatable] Given how popular `pandas` is, it's always reasonable guess, however, I've answered a few too many questions without a dataframe tagged to have it be the wrong framework.

Comment: @HenryEcker It is Pandas DF

Answer (score 0):

Bit hacky but one way using `pandas.Series.reset_index`:

```
def getloc(index):
    try:
        return df.loc[index[0], index[1]]
    except KeyError:
        return np.nan

new_df = df2.apply(lambda x: x.reset_index().apply(tuple, axis=1)).applymap(getloc)
print(new_df)
```

Output:

```
   X    Y
0  1  NaN
1  5  6.0
2  9  7.0
```